# Some gif are taking too much memory

Tags: ios, react-native, gif, animated-gif

I know it's a very common problem and [this link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1968#issuecomment-125550791) is clearly explained because this happens.

It struck me a lot that [react-native-flanimatedimage](https://github.com/nihgwu/react-native-flanimatedimage) exists, since, it seems that it solved the problem using [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) which is a very famous module for native IOS.

> The truth is that the module fulfills what it promises, but in exchange for conserving memory, completely destroys the animation of the gif, causing it to be seen in slow motion.

Even within the issues of the module many people report this same

https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=slow

The problem is that some solutions that I have tried do not work or are simply solutions for native IOS workers.

---

The gif that I am trying to load, increases about 300mb the memory of the device, for each time that i render the gif and in some cases and depending on the device, this is causing a memory crash.

**I'm not sure what the clean way to attack this problem is. Release the memory in some way, or if you continue on the path of trying to avoid that the memory is loaded so much, using FLAnimatedImage or some other tool that you can recommend me.**

Comment: Is using GIFs a must? Video formats are much less prone to this problem than GIF.

Comment: video is not possible, because I need to have a transparent background :(

Comment: @jose920405 Did you ever find a solution?